# derivation of image function

Tags: image, function

I have a problem with the second derivation of an image function I(x,y).
The first derivations are: 
`I_x(x,y) = I(x+1,y) - I(x,y)` and 
`I_y(x,y) = I(x,y+1) - I(x,y)`.

But when I try to derive `I_x` in x-direction again, I get this:
`I_xx(x,y) = I(x+2,y) - 2*I(x+1,y) + I(x,y)`, but the right answer seems to be this: `I_xx(x,y) = I(x+1,y) + I(x-1,y) -2*I(x,y)`. Where is my mistake? Can anybody please explain it?

Comment: You're not providing enough information here. What is the function `I`  supposed to be doing? Can you post the code here, or are you using a third-party library? If the latter, please tell us which library you are using.

Comment: The function I(x,y) is the intensity function of an image. It returns the intensity value at the position (x,y). The first and second derivations of I are used in image processing. For example to detect keypoints in an image you can use the gradient (1st derivation) and the hessian matrix (matrix of 2nd derivations).

Comment: I think this sounds more like a maths/engineering problem to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question can be seen in the following example.  In the "right" answer the second derivative at x is centered around the point x.  In your answer, the second derivative is centered around the point x+1.  It is good to have derivatives line up as much as possible in many applications.  In some sense you have the right answer just as well as the "right" answer. It is a matter of defining your alignment and being consistent.  Given an array (let's use 1 based arrays for the moment)

```
    x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4), x(5), x(6)
x = [3,    2,    1,    8,    9,    4]
```

The first derivative is

```
     x'(1), x'(2), x'(3), x'(4), x'(5)
f'(x)  = [3-2,   2-1,   1-8,   8-9,   9-4]
```

Notice that the x' has one element less than x.  We can get around this if we make assumptions on the boundary conditions, which we will not do at present.

The second derivative is

```
x'(1)-x'(2), x'(2)-x'(3), x'(3)-x'(4), x'(4)-x'(5)
```

We only have 4 points that have a valid second derivative.  In the way you computed the 2nd derivative you simple take the first second derivative to be x''(1).  In this way we get the labeling as follows:

```
        x''(1),      x''(2),      x''(3),     x''(4),
x''=[(3-2)-(2-1), (2-1)-(1-8), (1-8)-(8-9), (8-9)-(9-4)]
```

In general your second derivative which is what you came up with can be written as:

```
x''(p) = x(p+2)-2*x(p+1)+x(p)
```

In your second derivative valid indices take the values 1..4  You do not have defined x''(5) as that would require x(5+2)-2*x(5+1)+x(5) and the original array has only 6 elements so x(7) is undefined.

Another way to label the points with the 2nd derivatives centered and aligned such that the nth second derivative is centered around the nth point in the original array is as follows:

```
        x''(2),      x''(3),      x''(4),     x''(5),
x''=[(3-2)-(2-1), (2-1)-(1-8), (1-8)-(8-9), (8-9)-(9-4)]
```

In general this can be written as:

```
x''(p) = x(p+1)-2*x(p)+x(p-1)
```

Notice that this second derivative valid indices are in the range 2..5  In this case x''(1) is not defined as that would require x(1+1)-2*x(1)+x(1-1) and the original array since we have 1 based arrays does not have a value at x(0).

In both cases the form is the same.  It's just you are labeling the points differently.

Odd numbered derivatives we cannot center around points in a finite difference, whereas even numbered derivatives we can center to have more intuitive alignment for downstream calculations.